# Is it possible to create a new product by class methods in virtuemart 2?

Tags: php, virtuemart

I have developed a virtual store using virtuemart 2.0.10 and I need the products in a given category have a different flow of purchase.

Is there a way, from the data of an existing product (with name, price, description, etc.) to create a new product with new id and sku, using an image located in a known directory? All done on the front end, as user interaction, using classes of MVC framework of virtuemart 2.

Needs to be done this way for the product to be added to cart separately, even though the same product base, each with its resized image, and when you click it to open the product details displaying a custom image.

If anyone know a way to do, please help! I looked at the classes responsible for registering products in virtuemart but do not know how to do safely from the front-end.

The first step (redirect user to component and create a custom image) is already done and working, the image is saved in directory and its url recorded in session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `VirtuemartControllerProduct::CloneProduct` function.  It will point you down into the `VirtueMartModelProduct::createClone` function where the work actually goes down.

Comment: OK, i called VirtuemartControllerProduct::CloneProduct() on VirtueMartControllerProductdetails::display method, on the end. The product info appears without any layouts and nothing is created in back end. Should i call the method in another class? Should it be called after a POST request? I'm logged with super user on the front end.

Comment: Whoa, wait. I was calling by the wrong way... a minor correction and now its echoing "invalid token" after method CloneProduct is called

Comment: You're going to have to read through the code a bit if you want to be able to use it outside of the user interface...  I'm merely pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: OK, i noticed that the model class check the current token, and if it's not there, the operation is cancelled. I just comment the checkToken call to see what happens. It shows "Cloned succesfully" message, but it's not really there... I'm afraid the security gaps ain't worth the job. But ok, you really helped me! Thanks!

Comment: I've modified VM1.9 somewhat to support automated ordering via a particular product manufacturing company.  A quick look at VM2 this morning reveals much cleaner looking code in the 2.0 branch.., it will take a little time to get rolling, but I'm sure you can get it.  Just make sure you have a development environment and version control!